# Receive and read GATT notifications on Android

Tags: java, android

So right now, I'm currently using the `TI SensorTag` and edited it such that it will send a `GATT` notification with some data every time I press one of the switches on the device and followed this code where moisture is the data I'm trying to send.

```
static void sendData(void )
{
    int length=0;

    while(moisture[length] != NULL)
    { 
      length++; 
    }

    attHandleValueNoti_t nData;
    nData.len = length;
    nData.handle = length;

    osal_memcpy( &nData.value, &moisture, length );

    // Send the Notification
    GATT_Notification( 0, &nData, FALSE );
}
```

Now on the Java side, TI provided the `SensorTag` app source code so I'm editing that to receive the data and save it into a .txt file for later retrieval. I was able to get the app to create a new directory on startup if it does not exist and create the .txt file and populate it with random strings with the same button press as the one used to send the data. A quick question I had about this is should this be done or should I use separate buttons?

What I'm having a huge issue even understanding is how to read the incoming notification or data. From what I understand so far, you need to know the characteristic or something of the incoming notification to read it? I do have notifications enabled on my central device so I know that I have at least that covered. For this kind of data transfer, I don't need to use any `UUID` things, correct? And if I do, would I be able to piggyback on one of the existing sensor services to do so? Or perhaps use the test service?

I've read a decent amount on `BLE` communications but I just can't seem to get it. How do I read the incoming notification or data I sent from the `SensorTag` through BLE?

Comment: If this is a new notification, something that wasn't already in place by TI, then yes you need an UUID for that characteristic, and you need to register that notification. You should be able to look at one of the existing notifications (in both sets of code (client and server) to see how all of this is done. You should be able to "piggyback" onto one of the existing services, but if it's a new characteristic then it still needs to be setup as such with it's own UUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A quick question I had about this is should this be done or should I
>   use separate buttons?

It's totally your call. If I were you, I would stick on to one button since BLE devices are better if designed the most simplest way. KISS.

> From what I understand so far, you need to know the characteristic or something of the incoming notification to read it?

Yes, you need the same profile running on both the peripheral and the central to enable notifications. In Bluez for example, run the `bluetoothd` daemon with all experimental profiles to communicate with a TI Sensor tag like this: `bluetoothd -E` . The same logic applies for a central running on Java. Reference: **[http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Bluetooth-Communications-Sensing-Library/dp/1608075796](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1608075796)**

> For this kind of data transfer, I don't need to use any UUID things, correct?

No, you don't have to since you aren't creating a new service but rather using the moisture sensor service already available on the device.

> I've read a decent amount on BLE communications but I just can't seem to get it.

To know more about Bluetooth terminology such as profiles, services, characteristics, asymmetric architecture, etc, please read the following references to understand the theory behind what's taking place:

[http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Bluetooth-Communications-Sensing-Library/dp/1608075796](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1608075796) (use this if you are already into the technical details of the  project)

[http://www.amazon.com/Bluetooth-Low-Energy-Developers-Handbook/dp/013288836X/ref=pd_sim_14_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=13KZ3RZ0VW93CK91RCM3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013288836X) (this gives a more general picture of the BLE)

Comment: "No, you don't have to since you aren't creating a new service but rather using the moisture sensor service already available on the device." It's my understanding, at least with the BLE stack that I've developer with, you do indeed need a UUID per characteristic. The service has it's UUID and then the characteristic has a UUID. If it's a new  notification characteristic to the service then how does the master identify it if it doesn't have a UUID? A characteristic is a part of a service, a service can have many different characteristics.

Comment: You are right in saying that you need a UUID per characteristic and service. But you don't need to `create` any new UUID since it's already present on the Sensor Tag. All that is needed to be done is run `gattool`, setup notifications on the UUID of interest provided you have permissions to do so. No any unique definition of UUID is required since a new service/characteristic isn't being defined but rather the one already present on the device is used.

Comment: Okay, thanks. That's why I said "if it's a new notification", something that wasn't already created/existing. I know of Sensor Tag, but haven't worked with it, and I'm not familiar with `gattool`. I just know that if you're creating a new characteristic then you need a UUID for that characteristic. If op is working with an existing characteristic, something already made available by TI, then no he doesn't need to worry about it.

Comment: @Jerry I see! Making a new service seems quite harder compared to using an existing one. Each sensor is set to read at set intervals (~2-5 seconds) and this only occurs once a BLE connection exists with a phone. I was able to get the device to read from a sensor at set intervals without needing a connection. Currently, I'm not calling the above function through a service but by itself. My assumption here is that I should call it through a sensor service? Would this also imply that I would have to get rid of any code that sends data already so they don't cause any issues?

Comment: @Jerry And also on the Android side of things, would the already implemented methods of reading data for a sensor/service suffice? What I plan to do is just replace the data that the device would normally send every so often with my own data. It seems like the data would go through just fine to the phone since this should be the case?

Comment: @GregLee "My assumption here is that I should call it through a sensor service?" Nope, not necessarily. If the Sensor Tag sends the readings as a part of the broadcast message, then you don't have to associate the readings to a profile on the central. Eventually, if you really want to comply to standards then you need to set up communications using profiles. But it's not necessary. After all, BLE in essence, boils down to socket communications. How you choose to represent the data is upto the standards that define a protocol.

Comment: "On the Android side of things, would the already implemented methods of reading data for a sensor/service suffice?" - Yup, it should be fine.